# How to create table using sqlite database in android?

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

```
public class MyAct extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("MyDb",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MyTab (Month INT(2),Date INT(2),Year INT(4),Event VARCHAR;");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO MyTab VALUES (0,1,2012,'mini_proj');");
        db.close();

    }
}
```

I have written this small snippet to create a table, but it's not working. What is the problem with this code?

Comment: what do you mean by not working? is it a crash?

Comment: You're missing a `)`. Also, remove the `;`

Comment: @nandeesh no...in ddms it is not showing the name of database table

Answer (score 2):

In your first query, you are missing a closing brace:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MyTab (
    Month INT(2),
    Date INT(2),
    Year INT(4),
    Event VARCHAR;
```

It should be:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MyTab (
    Month INT(2),
    Date INT(2),
    Year INT(4),
    Event VARCHAR
)
```

Also, note that the query doesn't need to end with a `;`, as mentioned in the docs:

> **Parameters**
>   *sql* the SQL statement to be executed. **Multiple statements separated by semicolons are not supported.**

Also, you should **ALWAYS** check your LogCat output, since this should throw a `SQLiteException`.

---

Some further SQLite notes:

1. SQLite doesn't have a `VARCHAR`-type. It [only has `TEXT`](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) and will convert any text-like type into it.
2. Note that giving a length for a datatype is also ignored by SQLite:

> SQLite **does not impose any length restrictions (other than the large
>   global `SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH` limit)** on the length of strings, BLOBs or
>   numeric values.

Comment: I modified my code.but still its not reflecting in ddms.now what does that mean?

Comment: Read your LogCat output. Also, Datbase things should go into a `SQliteDatabaseHelper`.

Comment: Thanks for your replies.Ya...i have included SQLiteDatabaseHelper.

Comment: Actually i am using a date picker.i want to compare date selected in date picker with the date stored in database table,and display the event on that day.Whether my approach is right?please suggest me..