# uncaught error invalid_state_err dom exception 11 phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, exception, dom, phonegap-build

When I am trying to execute the code (its written in a html page), I am getting **uncaught error invalid_state_err dom exception 11** on this line-->

```
tx.executeSql("UPDATE DETAILS SET username='"+item.doc.username+"' where id="+item.doc._id);
```

**Full code:**

```
function init2(tx)
{
    var username = "abc";
    var password = "abc";

    $.ajax
    ({
        url: "http://10.6.121.55:4985/oms/_all_docs?include_docs=true",
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        mimeType: 'application/json',
        //dataType: 'jsonp',
        //  async: false,
        data: '{}',
        beforeSend: function (xhr){ 
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', make_base_auth(username, password)); 
        },
        complete: function(returnData) {

            alert(returnData); 
            alert(JSON.stringify(returnData));

            var syncData=JSON.stringify(returnData);
            ////////
            window.globalsyncedinData= $.parseJSON(syncData);
            alert("globalsyncedinData: "+window.globalsyncedinData);
            alert("globalsyncedinData_rows or syncData: "+window.globalsyncedinData.responseJSON.rows);
            var syncData= window.globalsyncedinData.responseJSON.rows;      
            /////

            $.each(syncData, function(i, item) {
                alert("Inside each ");
                //if(item.doc!=null)
                alert(item.doc.username);
                alert(item.doc._id);
                if(item.doc._id!="channelUsers"){      
                    alert("inside if");
                    tx.executeSql("UPDATE DETAILS SET username='"+item.doc.username+"' where id="+item.doc._id);
                    alert("username updated");
                    tx.executeSql("UPDATE DETAILS SET email='"+item.doc.email+"' where id="+item.doc._id);
                    alert("email updated");
                    tx.executeSql("UPDATE DETAILS SET mobile='"+item.doc.mobile+"' where id="+item.doc._id);
                    alert("mobile updated");

                    alert("SYNCED IN COMPLETE");
                }
            });
            //alert(data.total_rows);
            alert("all updation done");
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("ERROR in Authentication!");
            // localread();
        }
    });  
}
```

**FYI,**

```
{"rows":[

{"key":"1424951086535","id":"1424951086535","value":{"rev":"1-6f7d2dca1cc0045ec4f2d7d2aadfc31c"},"doc":{"_id":"1424951086535","_rev":"1-6f7d2dca1cc0045ec4f2d7d2aadfc31c","acresowned":"6","email":"email@go.com","gender":"Male","homephone":"9999999999","mobile":"1111111111","username":"amitabh"}}

,{"key":"1425032119480","id":"1425032119480","value":{"rev":"1-7022963a7705226e775e3ed298088abf"},"doc":{"_id":"1425032119480","_rev":"1-7022963a7705226e775e3ed298088abf","acresowned":"7","email":"ram@gmail.com","gender":"Male","homephone":"9876551235","mobile":"7653788999","username":"ram"}}

,{"key":"1425373604840","id":"1425373604840","value":{"rev":"1-a3bd70dcdca631e9f9abb9d2b2180583"},"doc":{"_id":"1425373604840","_rev":"1-a3bd70dcdca631e9f9abb9d2b2180583","acresowned":"","email":"","gender":"Male","homephone":"","mobile":"","username":"abc"}}
],

"total_rows":3,"update_seq":10}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, for I am new to this platform.
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: `syncData` is a string, not an array or object, why are you looping over it with `$.each()`?

Comment: Its an object actually.

Comment: No it isn't. It's the value returned by `JSON.stringify()`, which returns a string.

Comment: oops!My bad! Actually I want to iterate over each row, and hence the code. But I dont understand why the invalid state error DOM  exception!!

Comment: Look at the **Related** questions. It looks like that exception happens for a variety of errors that occur when processing an AJAX response.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the command should be tx.execSQL(); not tx.executeSQL();

Comment: Where did you get that from? https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/UsingtheJavascriptDatabase/UsingtheJavascriptDatabase.html says `executeSQL`

Comment: During android development we use execSQL.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13893473/how-to-create-table-using-sqlite-database-in-android or http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Database/Createtableinsertrecorddeleterecordsquerytableremovetable.htm